# Jersey, Spring - @Value annotation doesn't work in a class which implements ContainerRequestFilter interface

Tags: spring, jersey

I'm using Spring and Jersey in my application which is running under Tomcat. And it seems that spring cannot inject values into fields annotated by @Value in classes which are being managed by servlet container.

Here is my code:

ContainerRequestFilter:

```
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHORIZATION)
public class AuthorizationRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

  @Value("${prop.value}")
  private String value;

  @Override
  public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
    //...
  }
}
```

applicationContext.xml

```
    <context:property-placeholder
            location="classpath:properties/app.properties"
            ignore-resource-not-found="true"
            system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE"/>

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean id="authorizationRequestFilter" class="com.test.filters.AuthorizationRequestFilter"/>
```

Value field is always null. However @Autowired annotations seem to work fine in the same case.
So is there any way to inject property values into such classes?